# Strange! I know someone who can answer but I could not let him know!

Tags: support

There is a recent and interesting post on MO: [erdos-harary-tuttes-dimension-of-graph-progress-in-last-48-yrs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140768/erdos-harary-tuttes-dimension-of-graph-progress-in-last-48-yrs) that I know a friend of mine can answer. I had in mind to let him know via this feature:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

Then I realized that this box is not available for the questions that already have at least one answer. In other words, it seems that it is only available for the questions with no answer. Am I right? Of course, I can e-mail my friend independently. But, I cannot see the reason behind such distinction. Is there any reason? If not, I suggest to have that box for all questions.

Comment: Are you aware of 'share' that seems to provide a similar functionality and stays present? Since you did not mention it, I could imagine you are not and might find it suffcient, but also that your are but still want this, hence the question.

Comment: @quid Yes, I was aware of "share". But it seems that it has a rather different functionality. To be honest, I personally am more curious than in need of that box. If a question has it, why another hasn't.

Comment: Related post on meta.SE: [Under what conditions is a user invited to “share a link to this question”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258957) This came up in connection with this recent post: [Why do we link to Twitter, Facebook or Google+ below every question?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3095)

Answer (score 10):

As quid remarked, the share button below the post has exactly the same functionality.

[image: share button screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, at least in my situation the functionality is not exact. g+, f, and twitter are all filtered where I live, but e-mail is not. And for that reason, the box under unanswered questions works for me, but the share button does not so.

Comment: @Amir: That's what the url box is for. All the email link does is launch your program to compose emails and start an email with the link in the body. If you really need a button for email in the share box then post a clear and specific feature request here or on [meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: One might also mention that there are plenty of people who don't use G+, Facebook or Twitter (I stand before you as an example), but it's a safe bet that anyone who uses MO also uses email.