# Facebook and Twitter links disappear ungracefully

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

I am using Safari 16.1 on macOS 12.6.  The invitation to "Share a link to this question" appears for me like this:

[image: Share a link to this question via email, , or .]

I assume that the Twitter and Facebook links are not showing because of some ad-blocking extension, and I'm fine with that, but, if the links are going to disappear in the presence of ad-blocking, it seems like it might be desireable to try to degrade gracefully to something like "Share a link to this question via email."

As @AsafKaragila [points out](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5499/facebook-and-twitter-links-disappear-ungracefully#comment27959_5499), this is in no way MO-specific, but I have understood SO-wide bug reports to be acceptable here on MMO.  Though this is not a bug in the sense of a coding error, I thought it was surely a bug in the sense that it was unexpected behaviour.  However, as @MartinSleziak [points out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62322210#62322210) in chat, this issue has been known at least since 2013 (see [Know someone who can answer? Share list broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214355/know-someone-who-can-answer-share-list-broken), which has a [staff response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214356), and its [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/214355)), so I guess by this point it should be regarded as expected behaviour.

Comment: I'd imagine that it's not a bug, but a "feature", or at least an update to the UI? Probably [meta.se] contains more information.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, [agreed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5499/facebook-and-twitter-links-disappear-ungracefully#comment27959_5499), in the sense that I am sure that this is nothing MO-specific.  But I thought I'd understood that one could report general bugs—and so I'd call it, in the sense that it is surely unintended behaviour, even if it is acceptable to the developers—on specific Meta sites, and I definitely feel more comfortable here than on the main Meta.  If I was wrong, then I have no objection to closing this question.

Comment: I will just add a link to a previous feature request on this meta suggesting to remove the links to Twitter and Facebook (and - at the time - Google+): [Why do we link to Twitter, Facebook or Google+ below every question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3095)

Comment: Voting to close. If this is a bug at all, it is a bug in a *third-party ad-blocking software* that Stackexchange has no control over, and this is admitted in the question itself. Thus, the bug report is off-topic. If you find this behaviour to be a problem, you have to report it to developers of said ad-blocking software, not here.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, this behaviour is, if anything, an advantage, not a problem, for me, but I thought the developers might want to be aware of the interaction of their code with other commonly used code (even though that interaction is not their fault).  But, since @‍MartinSleziak points out that not only are they aware, but they have been for almost 9 years, I certainly don't have an objection to closing.

Comment: Strange, I do not see the question ("Know someone who can answer?"). I am using uBlock Origin as an ad blocker but I still see the Twitter and Facebook links; this suggests that there is no bug here, just that you have probably configured your ad blocker to use a social media block list, in which case what you see is absolutely normal.

Comment: @AlexM., [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27966), I am not quite sure what you are saying that you see vs. what you don't.  If you are not seeing the text "Know someone who can answer?" appearing beneath a question, then it's because it relies on some conjunction of conditions being satisfied (perhaps just that it is on the main site and does not yet have any answers). \\ Re the cause, I know it is the ad blocker, but thought the developers might care to know about this interaction. But it seems that they do know, and don't want to make changes, so I am fine with closing.

Comment: No, I was not saying that it is the ad blocker, it is probably one of the "lists" (or "filters") that your ad blocker uses. If you do not know what these are, though, this is probably not the appropriate place for explanations. Alternatively, this could be from your browser being configured to prevent tracking, so it could have nothing to do with the ad blocker. This is why I am saying that this is not a bug, but the normal consequence of how privacy settings are configured in your browser (probably very aggressively).

Comment: @AlexM., [yes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27976), I do know what all of these things are.  I guess you could say that it is not the ad blocker but the filter, and I did not mean to disagree; I was using "ad blocker" I suppose synecdochically (or maybe I mean metonymically; I never did properly understand the difference) to mean the ad blocker implementing the filter. Anyway, there is no question about *why* this is happening; I only didn't know if all relevant parties knew *that* it was happening.  But they do, so, again, I have no problem with closing.

Comment: Since [@AlexM.](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5499/facebook-and-twitter-links-disappear-ungracefully#comment27966_5499) mentioned that the question "Know someone who can answer?" was not visible to him, here's a post on Meta SE asking under what conditions this is shown: [Under what conditions is a user invited to "share a link to this question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258957)